# Type 2 IF Conditional. vs Type 3 Situation Comparison

Tags: conditional-constructions, irrealis-mood

**If I am standing there talking to someone while they are getting ready I can use TYPE 2? such as all of these?**

1. If you woke up earlier, then you wouldn’t need to rush.
2. If you didn’t leave so late, then you wouldn’t have to run to work.
3. If you weren’t running so far behind, then you wouldn’t have to hurry.
4. If you could get a ride, you could probably make it on time.
5. If you could hail down a taxi, then you might still make it.
6. Or if you were a magician, you could just teleport yourself there.
7. That would be really cool if that were actually possible.

**And if I am talking to him at work and he was late then I could change them to type 3? Such as?**

1. If you had woken up earlier, then you wouldn’t have needed to rush.
2. If you hadn't left so late, then you wouldn’t have had to run to work.
3. If you hadn't been running so far behind, then you wouldn’t have had to hurry.
4. If you could have gotten a ride, you could have probably made it on time.
5. If you could have hailed down a taxi, then you might have still made it.
6. Or if you had been a magician, you could have just teleported yourself here.
7. That would have been really cool if that had been actually possible.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Steve means that you have expressed your questions wrongly - you mean **can I use** and **could I change**.

Comment: My question is...are they all correct and are they used in the correct situation.  I am assuming they are, but checking if my assumption is correct.

Comment: "proofreading" questions are usually off-topic here. Is there some reason you think you might be incorrect or some sentence that confuses you?

Comment: Well If conditional are very difficult and confusing and there seems to be different answers everywhere.  like using WERE with he as in If I were him etc.  So I just wanted to check if my uses are correct in their corresponding situations as above.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't exactly asked how it should be...but i also think things like this are useful for other studying as they will access to more answers/possibilities with example sentences.

Comment: I would reduce the examples to two. Seeing 14 sentences, at a glance, it looks like you're asking the community for at least 7 different answers. You're not but you don't need a confirmation for each and everyone. Chose the one or two where you are least certain.

Comment: I just provided one of each kind.  I figured long and clear answers would be helpful to many.  I know I would appreciate that as i find many answers not good enough to answer what i need most times.  Everything feels so half-assed.  Since data on the internet is free..and unlimited library, I'd think it would be better that way..I only see the benefits and not the harm. ;)